# When does 50 questions per 30 days limit decay?

Tags: support, asking-questions, data-explorer, monthly-question-limit

I've been programming a lot last month and I've asked a lot of questions. Not all of them were good questions so definitely this limit has struck me where it was supposed to.

Still, it's very uncomfortable. Especially it's annoying that I can't tell whether I can ask question already. I've just spent 30 minutes writing a question to make sure it's a good question but it turned out that the limit is still active. That's strange because I last posted question 2 days ago.

Therefore my question is, how can I know when will I be able to post again? Maybe I could use data explorer for this?

Comment: See it this way: if you post all 50 in the same day, you'll have to wait 30 days to ask another one.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Here on meta, one moderator can close question as duplicate without voting or explanation? I was asking for a way to find out the actual time. Your "duplicate" doesn't describe anything near that.

Comment: Yes it does, and clearly so. [This is your 50th question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28722138/how-to-simulate-static-variable-in-java-interface-default-method), when [sorting by creation date](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&pagesize=50&q=user%3a607407%20is%3aquestion), and it was posted on Feb 25 at 14:52. Take 30 days from that time, meaning you should be able to ask your next question on March 27, 2015 at 14:52. And I'm not a moderator, just have a gold badge in [tag:support] as clearly indicated in the tooltip of the gold icon.

Comment: For completeness: the above assumes there are no deleted questions in that timespan (they do not appear on question list, but are included in the 50).  @ShadowWizard

Comment: @Woodface correct, only a mod can see those and tell for sure when next question can be posted, but OP can see recently deleted questions as well via the question tab in the profile.